# rust enums in primitive representations

Tags: rust, ffi

I've recently read through [Type Layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#type-layout), and I was surprised by the description of primitive repr on enums.
See [Primitive Representation of Enums With Fields](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#primitive-representation-of-enums-with-fields) and [Combining primitive representations of enums with fields and `#[repr(C)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#combining-primitive-representations-of-enums-with-fields-and-reprc).
My question is, aren't these two representations equivalent?

More concretely, consider this enum:

```
enum WithFields {
    A(u16),
    B(u8, u16),
    C(u32, u32),
}
```

If it was annotated with `repr(u8)`, it would have the same representation as `UnionWithTag` below:

```
#[repr(C)]
union UnionWithTag {
    a: VariantA,
    b: VariantB,
    c: VariantC,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum Tag {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(C)]
struct VariantA(Tag, u16);

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(C)]
struct VariantB(Tag, u8, u16);

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(C)]
struct VariantC(Tag, u32, u32);
```

If it was instead annotated with `repr(C, u8)`, it would have the same representation as `TaggedUnion` below:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct TaggedUnion {
    tag: Tag,
    payload: Union,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum Tag {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub union Union {
    a: PayloadA,
    b: PayloadB,
    c: PayloadC,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(C)]
struct PayloadA(u16);

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(C)]
struct PayloadB(u8, u16);

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(C)]
struct PayloadC(u32, u32);
```

Aren't `TaggedUnion` and `UnionWithTag` identical in layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, `VariantC`/`PayloadC` have an alignment of 4, while the rest of the `Variant`/`Payload`s have an alignment of 2.

In the `TaggedUnion` example, `Union` has an alignment of 4, which is the maximum alignment of its members. Therefore, `TaggedUnion` must place three bytes of padding in between the u8 tag and the union, in all cases, to satisfy the worst case of `PayloadC`.

However, the `Variant`s have more flexibility allowed to them. `VariantA`'s u16 member only needs an alignment of 2, so it only needs one byte of padding between the tag and its data. `VariantB` can tightly pack its data without any padding. `VariantC` still needs 3 bytes of padding. The extra padding, though, comes back when they are placed in the `Union`, but it is located at the end of the union.

So since the internally tagged `Variant`s know they will include a tag, they can move their data up closer to the tag, but since `Payload`s may exist as a separate structure outside of their tag, they need to be aligned themselves, making the two approaches layout-incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

It might look like they'd be identical, but the `repr(C, u8)` version will end up with more padding than the `repr(u8)` version. Consider a simplified version of the enum, with just the `B` variant:

```
enum WithFields {
    B(u8, u16),
}
```

as `repr(u8)`:

```
#[repr(C)]
union UnionWithTag {
    b: VariantB,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum Tag {
    B,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(C)]
struct VariantB(Tag, u8, u16);
```

and as `repr(C, u8)`:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct TaggedUnion {
    tag: Tag,
    payload: Union,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum Tag {
    B,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub union Union {
    b: PayloadB,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(C)]
struct PayloadB(u8, u16);
```

We'll work bottom-up to calculate the overall sizes of `TaggedUnion` and `UnionWithTag`.

- `PayloadB` requires a padding byte after the `u8` field to correctly align the `u16` field.
- `VariantB`'s fields all fit together with no padding (the `u8` tag and the `u8` field perfectly-align the `u16` field)
- `TaggedUnion` is a `u8` tag followed by (a union, containing only) `PayloadB`, which has align 2. This forces a padding byte after the tag, to align it correctly. Overall, size 6, align 2. 2 padding bytes overall.
- `UnionWithTag` is (a union, containing only) `VariantB`, which has size 4, align 2. No padding is used.

This isn't really a great exploration of *why* the layouts are not equivalent, but it is an effective proof-by-contradiction that they are indeed not equivalent.